# Как правильно передать json словарь с двумя одноименными параметрами в api

Tags: python, rest, test-automation

Суть в том, что нужно передавать файлы в параметре files по одному. Сколько файлов прикрепляется, столько раз следует повторить этот параметр

Тест имеет вид

```
def test_create_video_post_with_2_videos():
    request_post_create = PostController().create_post(files=video_kuplinov, data=post_json_video_foot)
    assert request_post_create['status']['statusCodeValue'] == 200
```

В методе PostController().create_post находится класс

```
class PostController(ApiClient):
    def create_post(self, files, data):
        "Метод для работы с "/api/v2/posts/create"
        :param files: принимает на вход файлы видео/картинок
        :param data: может принимать ID игры, на тему которой создается пост, ID предложенной игры,
        на тему которой создается пост, Id пользователя в игре
        "
        s = ApiClient.post(self, api_endpoint=url_create_post, files=files,
                           data=data)
        response_json = s.json()
        return response_json
```

В параметр files я передаю словарик, который содержит в себе видеофайлы

```
video_kuplinov = {
    'files': ('kuplinov1.mp4', open('files/kuplinov1.mp4', 'rb'), 'video/mp4'),
    'files': ('kuplinov2.mp4', open('files/kuplinov2.mp4', 'rb'), 'video/mp4')
}
```

Нужно как то этот словарик обернуть, чтобы тест смог взять параметр files с переданном в нем файле и затем взять второй раз параметр files с переданном в нем втором файле. Результатом будет созданный пост с двумя видеофайлами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files

```
video_kuplinov =  [
    ('files', ('kuplinov1.mp4', open('files/kuplinov1.mp4', 'rb'), 'video/mp4'),
    ('files', ('kuplinov2.mp4', open('files/kuplinov2.mp4', 'rb'), 'video/mp4')
]
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Некорректно написал описание
Суть в том, что нужно файлы передавать в параметре files по одному. Сколько файлов прикрепляется, столько раз следует повторить этот параметр

Comment: писал по памяти, неправильно написал, извиняюсь) исправил и ссылку на доки добавил

Comment: если не сработает, то показывай что там в методе  PostController().create_post

Comment: в описание добавил

Comment: все, заработало, там скобок просто не хватало) спасибо!